# session data lost when changing the page

Tags: php, iis

I tested the following php manual example, but it gives these errors:

- Notice: Undefined index: favcolor in C:\wamp\www\sessions_practice\page2.php on line 8
- Notice: Undefined index: animal in C:\wamp\www\sessions_practice\page2.php on line 9
- Notice: Undefined index: time in C:\wamp\www\sessions_practice\page2.php on line 10"

when clicking the page2 link.

page1.php

```
<?php
// page1.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #1';

$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
 $_SESSION['time']     = time();

// Works if session cookie was accepted
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a>';

// Or maybe pass along the session id, if needed
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php?' . SID . '">page 2</a>';
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
// page2.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #2<br />';

 echo $_SESSION['favcolor']; // green
echo $_SESSION['animal'];   // cat
 echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);

// You may want to use SID here, like we did in page1.php
 echo '<br /><a href="page1.php">page 1</a>';
?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Check if the session cookie is being set. Watch for headers being sent by PHP because you're running on IIS.

Comment: Are you getting an error for `SID` ? in page one

Comment: WOW I never knew when you start a session you get  `SID` , something new everyday!

Comment: In page 1 i dont get any errors. but when i click page 2 link, it gives errors.i am using php 5.4.3

Comment: The script works fine for me.

Comment: i think this is my settings problem. if so how can I solve this?plz help me...